# Update failing because of RLS for SELECT

Tags: postgresql, supabase, row-level-security, supabase-database

I have a table `Account(id, status, owner)` with the following RLS policies:

**For SELECT:**

```
CREATE POLICY "Allow users to select active accounts" ON "public"."Account"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR SELECT
TO public
USING ((owner = auth.uid()) AND (status = 'active'))
```

**For UPDATE:**

```
CREATE POLICY "Allow users to update their own accounts" ON "public"."Account"
AS PERMISSIVE FOR UPDATE
TO public
USING ((owner = auth.uid()))
WITH CHECK ((owner = auth.uid()))
```

Selecting works fine, but when I try updating a record to `status='deleted'` I get an RLS violation error. I am using the JS SDK (latest version) for this update with this code:

```js
await supabase.from("Account").update({"status":"deleted"}).eq('id', id)
```

If I change the SELECT policy and remove the condition `AND (status = 'active')` -- then the update works. So it seems that this is what's triggering the issue. However, as I am not selecting with the update (and it should return minimal by default), I don't understand why it's causing this issue. What am I missing here?

Comment: From the manual: `SELECT rights are also required on the relation being updated, and the appropriate SELECT or ALL policies will be applied in addition to the UPDATE policies.`. Both SELECT and UPDATE policies must match

Comment: To my understanding, SELECT policies are applied **before** the update (USING), but they don't have to pass for the row **after** the update. Is that correct?